# Chrome Extension: after update to 59 version iframe lose event handlers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Our business relies on an application which is a Chrome extension. Since Chrome updated to version 59 we started seeing our event listeners for iframe listeners disappear randomly. This in turn breaks a lot of the logic in the tool.

We've tried everything: the developer documentation is opaque on this issue and we weren't able to find a solution from discussions in the developer community.

Here is example of code:

```
$(frame).load(function () {
    var frameContext = $(this);
    frameContext.contents().find('body').append(options.html);

    setTimeout(function () {
        var doc = frameContext.contents()[0];
        if (!doc) {
            console.log("iframe document is not ready"); 
            // just ensure, that document is already exist
            return false;
        }

        var closeButton = doc.getElementById("closeButton");


        closeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log("Callback function just dissapears.");

            ...
        }, true);
    }, 600);
});
```

1. It worked before Chrome released 59 version.
2. Console doesn't show any errors.
3. I've tried jquery listeners `on(), click()`. It doesn't help.
4. **BUT! Everything works well if you turn on the Chrome DevTool!**

Thanks!

Comment: what is the iframe src? just a regular URL?

Comment: `Eve works well` - who is Eve?

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry, just typo.

Comment: @JaromandaX no. I created iframe and insert html inside.
`frameContext.contents().find('body').append(options.html);`

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks. Does Iframe have any limitations for eventListeners? Can I read somewhere about changes, something like a release note for developers?

Comment: There shouldn't be. Sounds like you're hitting a bug. Try Chrome canary 62 and other versions. Consider reporting on https://crbug.com

Comment: @wOxxOm you're right! In canary 62 everything works! But, we need wait for 2 releases :D
 61 contain this bug. Damn.

Thank you so much